# Which compilers support the Haskell FFI

Tags: haskell, ffi

Are there any other compilers than ghc that support the Haskell Foreign Function Interface as in [The Haskell 98 Foreign Function Interface 1.0
An Addendum to the Haskell 98 Report](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/ffi/ffi.pdf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[nhc98](http://www.haskell.org/nhc98) states that it supports the [ffi](http://www.haskell.org/nhc98/ffi.html):

> The nhc98 compiler contains an implementation of the standard foreign function interface that is also available in Hugs and ghc. The most recent released version of nhc98 implements the latest standard syntax for foreign function declarations, as specified at: [http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/ffi/](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Echak/haskell/ffi/)

I'm not sure whether

> Compliance notes
>
> - Supported calling conventions are: ccall, noproto, and cast. (The latter two are non-standard, see below.) Unsupported calling conventions are: stdcall, jvm, dotnet, cplusplus.
> - foreign import "wrapper" is not yet supported.
> - The annotation unsafe has no special meaning in nhc98; it is purely a speed optimisation for ghc.
> - A foreign export specification is treated as the actual type signature for the exported function. You are not allowed a second (possibly more general) type signature.
> - Hence, you cannot foreign export any function that requires a class dictionary.

means that the support is only partial, or whether these are optional things, but nhc98 is, as far as I know the only compiler except GHC that supports at least a large chunk of the FFI spec. (hugs is not a compiler but an interpreter, it supported [much of] the FFI spec as that was when hugs development ended [2006].)

Note, however, that nhc98 isn't much maintained anymore either.

Of the actively maintained implementations, [jhc](http://repetae.net/computer/jhc/), and [UHC](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/UHC) support only a small part of the FFI (primitive foreign imports), according to their respective home pages, so GHC is basically without competition.

Answer (score 0):

All Haskell  implementations support the FFI, as by definition, it isn't a Haskell compiler if it doesn't implement the language specification (which includes [the FFI](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html).

This means Hugs, GHC, nhc98 at a minimum.

Comment: But so GHC is not a Haskell Compiler, since for example the Report states that mutually recursive modules are allowed but GHC does not fully support them.